# NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#email_contact , rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a contact form for my app, but I get an error: `undefined method 'send_email' for ProductMailer:Class.`

My Staticpagescontroller is:

```
def email_contact
  ProductMailer.send_email().deliver
  redirect_to contact_url
end
```

My Emailer is :

```
class Contact < ActionMailer::Base
default from: "from@example.com"

# Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
# with the following lookup:
#
#   en.contact.send_email.subject
#

def send_email
  @greeting = "Hi"

  mail to: "example@example.com"
end
end
```

And my route is:

```
 match '/show/:id', to: 'stores#show', via: 'get', :as=> 'show'
 get  "emailproduct/:id" => "products#email_product", :as => "email_product"
 get "emailcontact" => "static_pages#email_contact", :as => "email_contact"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename class Contact to ProductMailer

Answer (score 0):

You've specified a wrong class name. In your mailer class, you've defined `Contact` class but you've used `ProductMailer` in your controller action. It should be:

```
def email_contact
  Contact.send_email().deliver
  redirect_to contact_url
end
```